# creating JSON request URL in Objective C via DropBox SDK for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, dropbox

I'm rather new to trying to figure out how JSON and the DropBox API function with the iphone SDK that DB has release for the iPhone. I understand how both technologies work in general and that you have to build a dictionary into a request and get another dictionary back, but I can't find a solid example of how to do anything specifically enough online in Objective C.

I just need one example of how to retrieve for instance the user's profile information by creating a JSON request to fetch info from the drop-box server.

I've been able to log the user in and linking the device using the consumer key and consumer secret but what's next I'm a little at a loss.

MANY thanks for any guidance or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send your data

Example for POST methods:

```
url = @"https://api.dropbox.com/<version>/account/"
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:value forKey:@"callback"];
```

Example for GET methods (URL queries):

```
  NSString *urlString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"https://api.dropbox.com/<version>/account/info
"] autorelease];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?callback=whatever&status_in_response=something"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDidFinishForThreadID:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

To retrieve JSON values and convert them into Dictionary

```
SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)[json objectWithString:responseString];
```

You will need JSON Framework: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

And also ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Haven't tested it with dropbox, but should be this way.